# MPMoviePlayerController error _itemFailedToPlayToEnd while playing RTMP video link iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurl

I am trying to play a video like:

```
- (void) playMovie {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"rtmp://122.129.75.174:61935/live/peghamtvX007"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                           initWithContentURL:url];

    self.videoController = controller; //Super important
    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

    [self.view addSubview:controller.view]; //Show the view
    [controller play]; //Start playing
}
```

But it failed to play. Here is error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Can i play rtmp link in `WebView` using `MPMoviePlayerController`? and also help me out in this error.

Comment: Did you found any solution ? i am also facing same issue..